# Google maps info window show/hide action

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm trying to set up some show/hide action on google maps marker info window. I do this by `mouseover` and `mouseout` events, but i have some conflict with jQuery... So, the code:

```
newmarker['infowindow'] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: html
});

google.maps.event.on(newmarker, {
    mouseover : function(){
        this['infowindow'].open(map, this)
    },
    mouseout : function() {
        this['infowindow'].close(map, this)
    }
});
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Like

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});

// assuming you also want to hide the infowindow when user mouses-out
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
    infowindow.close();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/JXqLa/128/)

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/JXqLa/133/)

Comment: you can use it directly

Comment: thx for help, its work perfect, sorry for not response but just 2day i saw it